# Accessing url parameters in Padrino\Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I am building a simple application with Padrino

I have set up a link to pass parameters as follows:

```
.new_update=button_to pat(:new_update), url(:updates, :new), :status_notice_id => @status_notice.id, :method => :get, :class => :button_to
```

Which is rendered as follows:

```
 <form class="button_to" action="/admin/updates/new" status_notice_id="2" method="get">
```

My  admin controller looks like:

```
 get :new do 
      @status_notice_id = params[:status_notice_id]
      @update = Update.new :status_notice_id => @status_notice_id
      render 'updates/new'
    end
```

However I am at a loss as how to successfully pull the parameter into my code. Any ideas? I'm new to both sinatra and padrino, so I'm guessing I haven't gotten a handle on routing correctly but I'm getting increasingly confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `url(:updates, :new, :status_notice_id => @status_notice.id)` to get `/admin/updates/new?status_notice_id=2` URL.

In your code `status_notice_id` applies to `button_to` helper method and goes to html attributes.

Comment: Hey ujifgc, 
Good call that worked a treat, thanks for the help!